# Implement Hash table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hashtable

I'm having trouble getting writing the getter method of my hash class based on what I have in the setter class.

The error I'm getting is: `error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

```
setItem = (key, value, value2) => {
    const idx = HashStringToInt(key, this.table.length);
    if (this.table[idx]) {
        this.table.push([key,[value, value2]]);
    } else {
        this.table[idx] = [[key, [value, value2]]]
    }        
}

getItem = key => {
    const idx = HashStringToInt(key, this.table.length);

    if (!this.table[idx]) {
        return null;
    }
    return this.table[idx].find(x => x[0] === key)[1]; //this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: If you pass `this.table.length` to your hash function *and* you keep changing the length, how are you expected to receive the same hashas before and after adding an item?

Comment: I see what you're saying, but how then can I write this to essentially have a key go to two values a = b,c ?

Comment: If you want two values per key, then a bog standard hash table where you store arrays of two items seems enough. The problem here isn't the number of values but that the hashing is unstable - after you push to the array any future hash recalculations will take the new length of the array. I don't know your hashing implementation but it seems a reasonable assumption that `HashStringToInt("foo", 1)` and `HashStringToint("foo", 2)` will produce different results. You can remedy that by using a constant size of the array, so the hash identity of the same key is stable.

Comment: In addition to hashing problems, isn't the `if` statement in `setItem` flipped around? If a given key *exists*, then a new item is pushed to the array, if it *doesn't exist*, then a key is overwritten.

Comment: thanks for the input but I seemed to have got it to do what I wanted now

Comment: It's a simple typo `this.table.push([key,[value, value2]]);` => `this.table[idx].push([key,[value, value2]]);` You forgot the index

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
this.table.push([key,[value, value2]]);
```

To:

```
this.table[idx].push([key,[value, value2]]);
```

Seems to give me the desired results